# SQL Query to return Highest and Lowest for each Unique Entry in other column

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by

Sorry if my title is a bit confusing, I wasn't sure how to word it.

I have a table that represents a bus schedule. It has an entry for each stop made on every trip made, as well as the arrival and departure times, and the order of stops. Ex:

```
Trip_ID  Arrival     Departure     Stop_ID  Stop_Seq
Trip1    06:00:00    06:00:30      465      1
Trip1    06:03:45    06:04:15      474      2
...
Trip1    06:53:15    06:53:45      169      27
Trip1    06:56:30    06:57:00      311      28
Trip2    07:02:00    07:02:30      534      1
Trip2    07:03:45    07:04:15      700      2
...
Trip2    07:41:50    07:42:20      164      35
Trip2    07:45:30    07:46:00      311      36
```

My goal is to write a query that will return two results for each unique Trip, the record with the lowest Stop_Seq and the record with the highest Stop_Seq (per trip).
Ex:

```
Trip_ID  Arrival     Departure     Stop_ID  Stop_Seq
Trip1    06:00:00    06:00:30      465      1
Trip1    06:56:30    06:57:00      311      28
Trip2    07:02:00    07:02:30      534      1
Trip2    07:45:30    07:46:00      311      36
```

I've tried to do something like the following, but I don't have a great grasp of Group By logic.

```
SELECT trip_id,arrival,departure,stop_id,MIN(stop_seq),MAX(stop_seq)
FROM stop_times
GROUP BY trip_id;
```

Unfortunately it gets upset that I'm not also grouping by the times and stop, but that won't work, I don't want all the times, only the first and last.

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following query will return each `Trip` record with its lowest `Stop_Seq` and the highest `Stop_Seq`.

```
SELECT *
FROM stop_times a
WHERE a.Stop_Seq=(
    SELECT  MAX(b.Stop_Seq)
    FROM stop_times b
    WHERE a.Trip_ID=b.Trip_ID
)
or 
a.Stop_Seq=(
    SELECT  MIN(b.Stop_Seq)
    FROM stop_times b
    WHERE a.Trip_ID=b.Trip_ID
)
```

Comment: This one ended up working best for me. @Zorko solution didn't play well with Access, it didn't like the use of aliases in the inner join statement. Thanks @Abhilash!

Answer (score 1):

If Stop_Seq is unique, then you can use a derived table.  The derived table takes the Min and Max Stop_Seq from the stop_times table. The receiving query can join back to reacquire the details:

```
SELECT dT.Trip_ID
      ,ST.Arrival
      ,ST.Departure
      ,ST.Stop_ID
      ,dT.Stop_Seq

  FROM (
         SELECT Trip_ID, MIN(Stop_Seq) AS Stop_Seq FROM stop_times GROUP BY Trip_ID
         UNION ALL
         SELECT Trip_ID, MAX(Stop_Seq) FROM stop_times GROUP BY Trip_ID         
       ) AS dT 
           INNER JOIN stop_times ST 
             ON dT.Trip_ID = ST.Trip_ID
            AND dT.Stop_Seq = ST.Stop_Seq
ORDER BY Trip_ID
```

Gives Output:

```
Trip_ID Arrival     Departure   Stop_ID Stop_Seq
Trip1   06:00:00    06:00:30    465     1
Trip1   06:56:30    06:57:00    311     28
Trip2   07:02:00    07:02:30    534     1
Trip2   07:45:30    07:46:00    311     36
```

Here is the complete code: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b9efc/1/0

The reason it did not work as you expect is because GROUP BY removes duplicates, but the values in columns Arrival, Departure, and Stop_ID are changing.  These changing values defeat the GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution. Calculate, using a subquery, in two separate queries the lowest stop_seq per trip and the highest stop_seq per trip. 
Combine the results using UNION.

```
SELECT a.Trip_ID,a.Arrival, a.Departure, a.Stop_ID, a.Stop_Seq
FROM stop_times as a
WHERE a.Stop_Seq =
(
SELECT Min(b.Stop_Seq)
FROM stop_times as b
WHERE b.Trip_ID =a.Trip_ID
)
UNION SELECT a.Trip_ID,a.Arrival, a.Departure, a.Stop_ID, a.Stop_Seq
FROM stop_times as a
WHERE a.Stop_Seq =
(
SELECT Max(b.Stop_Seq)
FROM stop_times as b
WHERE b.Trip_ID =a.Trip_ID
);
```